# How to sort a list of DateTime in flutter?

Tags: flutter

Hello I have a list of Date

```
  dateList = [ '2019-12-03 00:25', '2019-12-03 00:20', '2019-12-03 00:45', '2019-12-03 00:46'];
```

I try to sort like this

```
  dateList = [ '2019-12-03 00:20', '2019-12-03 00:25', '2019-12-03 00:45', '2019-12-03 00:46'];
```

I tried

```
dateList.sort((a,b) => a.compareTo(b));
```

but result null ...

Comment: you have a list of `DateTime` objects so sort that list, not a list of `String`s, something like: `var dateList = strList.map(DateTime.parse).toList()..sort(); `

Comment: `DateTime` is `Comparable` so there is no need to pass anything to `sort()` method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the dates are of `String` data type, while using `sort` method, we need to convert the comparators into `String`. Working code below:

`print(dateList..sort((a,b) => a.toString().compareTo(b.toString())));`

note: I used method cascade (..), since sort is a void method.

output:

`[2019-12-03 00:20, 2019-12-03 00:25, 2019-12-03 00:45, 2019-12-03 00:46]`

Hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below code which is in JavaScript.

```
var dateList = [ '2019-12-03 00:25', '2019-12-03 00:20', '2019-12-03 00:45', '2019-12-03 00:46'];

dateList.sort((a,b) => new Date(a).getTime() - new Date(b).getTime());
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried but new Date(a).getTime()  doesn't work